# merge many collection lists into a single collection list in entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

> I have Lots of collection list in my page what i want to do just
>   merge all collection list into single collection list in entity
>   framework.I already Defined class  or model but when i retrieve it
>   doesn't return any thing.

```
        using (FinanceEntities fentities = new FinanceEntities(value.credentials))
        {
            try

            {   
                int str=DateTime.DaysInMonth(Valcol.year,Valcol.month);
                string FD = Valcol.year + "-" + Valcol.month + "-" + "01";
                string LD = Valcol.year + "-" + Valcol.month + "-" + str;
                DateTime FirstDate = DateTime.Parse(FD);
                DateTime vdate = DateTime.Parse(LD);
                List<PayNoModel> PayNoModel = GetPayNoModel(value);

               List<VoucherNoModel> VoucherNoModel=GetVoucherNoModel(value);
                List<PayNoModel> PayNoModel2 = GetPayNoModel2(value);
                List<PayNoModel> PayNoModel3 = GetPayNoModel3(value);
                List<VoucherNoModel> VoucherNoModel2 = GetVoucherNoModel2(value);
                List<ChequeNoModel> ChequeNoModel = GetChequeNoModel(value);
                List<VoucherNoDiffModel> VoucherNoDiffModel = GetVoucherNoDiffModel(value);
                List<VoucherNoNarationModel> VoucherNoNarationModel = GetVoucherNoNarationModel(value);


                query = (from p in PayNoModel
                         from v in VoucherNoModel
                         from p2 in PayNoModel2
                         from p3 in PayNoModel3
                         from v2 in VoucherNoModel
                         from ch in ChequeNoModel
                         from voucdiff in VoucherNoDiffModel
                         from voucnarr in VoucherNoNarationModel
                         select new ReconcileReportModel
                         {


                         }).ToList<ReconcileReportModel>();
    }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var s = ex.Message;
            }

        }
        return query;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Hint dictionary.

Comment: yes but it only throw error and i just wanna to store whole data into single because i don't wanna to hit controller again and again

Comment: "it doesn't return any thing" - because you select nothing. The select new {..} is empty. Just list the collections in the select new {..} part.

Comment: i know i don't select any thing because if i select something than it through error. Might be syntax was incorrect. What i want to do select all list that i mentioned above.I don't know correct syntax for calling list.

Comment: are you trying to Union the lists?